# loggin with realtime database Firebase ( Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

So I want to log in with a certain role where I try to login with the user role, but it always goes into the else condition, because `snapshot.child(uid).child("role").equals("user")` this condition always false. Is there any solution to this problem?

[this is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYReb.png)

and this is my code :

```
package com.example.finalproject2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginScreenUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView phone,pass;
    private Button button;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomorTelp);
        pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passUser);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loads);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.loginUser:
                userlogin();
        }
    }

    private void userlogin() {
        String nomor = phone.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = pass.getText().toString().trim();


//        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild("role").equalTo("user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.child(nomor).exists()  && snapshot.child(password).exists() && snapshot.child(uid).child("role").equals("user")){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreenUser.this,"Login Succes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    back();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreenUser.this,"Data Belum Terdaftar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
    private void back() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String phoneTxt = phone.getText().toString();
            final String passwordTxt = password.getText().toString();

            if (phoneTxt.isEmpty() || passwordTxt.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please Enter Your Phone Number Or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasChild(phoneTxt)){
                            final String getpassword = snapshot.child(phoneTxt).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                            if (getpassword.equals(passwordTxt)){
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Successfully login! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,HomeScreen.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Phone Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I have done this. I think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using:

```
snapshot.child(uid).child("role").equals("user")
```

It basically means that you try to check if the full URL for the above reference is equal to "user". Which obviously will always return false since that URL can never be equal to the "user" String. The [toString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#public-string-tostring) method of the [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) class returns:

> The full location URL for this reference.

To solve this problem, you have to get the value that corresponds to the `role` field as a String:

```
snapshot.child(uid).child("role").getValue(String.class).equals("user")
//
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?